# Nonsingular Matrix algebra proof

Tags: matrices

Consider a nonsigular $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and $n\times 1$ vectors $x$ and $y$.

(a) Prove that $$\det(A+xy^\top) = \det(1+y^\top A^{-1}x).$$
(b) Use direct verification to show that:
$$(A+xy^\top)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \cfrac{A^{-1}xy^\top A^{-1}}{1+y^\top A^{-1}x}.$$
(c) What happens if
$
1+y^\top A^{-1} = 0$ ?

Comment: If you created that in $\LaTeX$, then you can post the equations parts here enclosed in \$s just like you would with $\LaTeX$

Comment: Keep the good work with $\LaTeX$, I just rewrite it..

Comment: That's just it, last time I tried to post the code of a problem from latex it wasn't working, so if I put the latex code pasted into the problem space enclosed by $'s it will work?

Comment: @jrmerrit See the MathJax tutorials on our site for more information; in general: Most will work, some will not. `$A$` produces inline-math and `$$A$$` produces displaystyle math on a separate line:$$$$
$\text{this is inline}$,$$\text{this is displaystyle}$$

Comment: @jrmerrit What have you tried for this problem so far?

Comment: right now I'm working through both sides of the equation in part a) to find where they are equivalent in form

Comment: I presume you are missing an $x$ in (c)?

Comment: yes after A^(-1)

Answer (score 0):

For (a) consider the eigenvalues of the dyad $u v^T$:
If $u v^T x = \lambda x$ for some non-zero $x$, then since $u v^T x = v^T x u$, we see that either $\lambda = v^T u =0 $ or
$x$ is a multiple of $u$, and $\lambda = v^T u $. Since $\dim \ker v^T = n-1$, we see that $uv^T$ has $n-1$ zero eigenvalues and one eigenvalue at $v^Tu$. Hence the eigenvalues of $I+uv^T$ are $n-1$ ones and $1+v^Tu$. Hence $\det(I+u v^T) = 1+v^Tu$.

Since $A+x y^T = A(I+A^{-1}x y)$, we have $\det(A+x y^T) = \det A \det (I+A^{-1}x y) =  (1+y^TA^{-1} x) \det A$.

(b) follows by multiplying. Alternatively, note that
$(I+uv^T)(I-\beta u v^T) = I + (1-\beta(1+v^Tu)) u v^T$, hence if
$\beta = {1 \over 1+v^T u}$, then (assuming $1+v^T u \neq 0$), we have
$(I+u v^T)^{-1} = I -{1 \over 1+v^T u} u v^T$.
Since $(A+x y^T)^{-1} = (I+A^{-1}x y)^{-1} A^{-1}$, we have the desired result.

(c) If $1+y^TA^{-1}x=0$, then $A+x y^T$ is not invertible as it has an eigenvalue at zero.
In particular, $(A+x y^T) A^{-1}x = A(I+A^{-1}x y) A^{-1}x = (1+y^TA^{-1}x)x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I insert here the part of question, preventing it from reediting. 
"Consider a nonsigular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and $n\times 1$ vectors $x$ and $y$.

(a) Prove that
$$
\det(A+xy^⊤)=\det(1+y^⊤A^{−1}x)."
$$
Here is a counterexample (if my calculations are correct).
$$
A:=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 \\
   4 & 3 \\
  \end{array} } \right],\qquad 
x:=\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   1 \\
   5 \\
  \end{array} } \right],\qquad
y:=\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   a \\
   b \\
  \end{array} } \right].
$$
Then 
$$
\det(A+xy^⊤)=-5+b-7a,
$$
and
$$
\det(1+y^⊤A^{−1}x)=\frac{1}{25}(5-b+7a)^2.
$$
More generally, $\det(A+xy^⊤)=\det(A+AA^{-1}xy^⊤)=
\det(A)\det(I+A^{-1}xy^⊤)=\det(A)\det(I+(A^{-1}x)y^⊤)=\det(A)\det(I+y^⊤(A^{-1}x))=\det(A)\det(I+y^⊤A^{-1}x)$,

where we used $\det(CD)=\det(DC)$, $\det(I+CD)=\det(I+DC)$. The last one is the [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem).

(b) We will use the identity $(I+P)^{-1}=(I+P)^{-1}(I+P-P)=I-(I+P)^{-1}P$.
\begin{align}
(A+xy^T)^{-1} &=(A+AA^{-1}xy^T)^{-1}\\
&=[A(I+A^{-1}xy^T)]^{-1}\\
&=(I+A^{-1}xy^T)^{-1}A^{-1}\quad(\text{using the identity it follows)}\\
&=\left[I-\frac{A^{-1}xy^T}{I+A^{-1}xy^T} \right]A^{-1}\\
&=A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}xy^TA^{-1}}{I+A^{-1}xy^T}.
\end{align}

(c) From (b) it follows that $(A+xy^T)^{-1}$ does not exist.